# Checking duplicate email when editing user profile in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check the duplicate email while I am logged in as a user and editing my own profile.

But when the email entered is the email of current logged in user and I do not want to update my current email then also I am getting a duplicate email error message.

accounts/forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        fields = ("organisation", "phone_number")

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(label=_("Phone (Please state your country code eg. +44)"))
    organisation = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['first_name'] = self.instance.user.first_name
        self.initial['last_name'] = self.instance.user.last_name
        self.initial['email'] = self.instance.user.email

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Field("first_name", wrapper_class="col-sm-6"),
            Field("last_name", wrapper_class="col-sm-6"),
            css_class = "row"
        ),
        Div(
            Field("organisation", wrapper_class="col-sm-6"),
            Field("email", wrapper_class="col-sm-6"),
            css_class = "row"
        ),
        Div(
            Field("phone_number", wrapper_class="col-sm-6"),
            css_class = "row"
        ),
    )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a different email address.')
            return email

    def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        self.instance.user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        self.instance.user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        self.instance.user.save()
        return super(UserProfileForm, self).save(commit, *args, **kwargs)
```

How can I check if the entered email is a new email and if it is new email then check duplicate function else ignore email field and update other fields.

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi can you look at this post,this may be help you [check if email exist or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602446/7261317)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `exclude` filter after your `filter` in order to exclude the current logged in user from your query. Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters):

```
User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(id=self.user.id)
```

It does mean however that your view will need to pass the current user to the form, so you should add that as init argument to the form initialisation (so that `self.user = user`)

Comment: I am editing the user profile in a popup form and the form has current user already. `form = POPUP_FORMS[key]['form'](instance=instance, initial={"user": request.user})`

Comment: Sorted. I had to use `self.user = self.instance.user` under __init__function. Many thanks for your help.