# django 1.11 raise forms.validationError not showing the error in html

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, validationerror

I've tried looking around for solutions on how to check if a form's name is already existing in the database. I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600784/django-1-9-check-if-email-already-exists?answertab=votes#tab-top) to figure out how, and it is indeed not allowing duplicate names to be entered. But where I expected one, I did not get an error message. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so if anyone can tell me what I should do, that would be really useful!

addgame.html:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% if form.non_field_errors %}
              {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                {{ error }}
              {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.name.label_tag }}
            {% render_field form.name class="form-control" %}
            <br>
            {{ form.genre.label_tag }}
            {% render_field form.genre class="form-control" %}
            <br>
            {{ form.image.label_tag }}
            {{ form.image }}
          </div>
          <hr>
          <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
```

views.py:

```
def addgame(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = InfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        infolist = form.save(commit=False)
        infolist.created_date = timezone.now()
        infolist.save()
        return redirect('index')
else:
    form = InfoForm()
return render(request, 'ranking/addgame.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class InfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = GameInfo
    fields = ('name', 'image', 'genre')

def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    try:
        match = GameInfo.objects.get(name=name)
    except GameInfo.DoesNotExist:
        return name
    raise forms.ValidationError('This game has already been added to the list.')
```

not sure if needed, so I'll post models.py as well:

```
class GameInfo(models.Model):
GAME_CHOICE = [
    ("BMU", "Beat 'em up"),
    ("FT", "Fighting"),
    ("PF", "Platform"),
    ("FPS", "Shooter"),
    ("SV", "Survival"),
    ("ST", "Stealth"),
    ("AA", "Action Adventure"),
    ("EX", "Exploring"),
    ("SH", "Survival horror"),
    ("IF", "Interactive fiction"),
    ("IM", "Interactive movie"),
    ("VN", "Visual novel"),
    ("ARP", "Action role-playing"),
    ("JRP", "Japanese role-playing"),
    ("TRP", "Tactical role-playing"),
    ("CAM", "Construction and management"),
    ("LS", "Life simulation"),
    ("SP", "Sports"),
    ("VH", "Vehicle"),
    ("MOBA", "Multiplayer online battle arena"),
    ("RTS", "Real-time strategy"),
    ("RTT", "Real-time tactics"),
    ("TBS", "Turn-based strategy"),
    ("TBT", "Turn-based tactics"),
    ("MMORPG", "MMORPG"),
    ("MMOFPS", "MMO-FPS"),
    ("MMOR", "MMO Racing"),
    ("CG", "Cardgame"),
    ("PAC", "Point and Click"),
    ("MG", "Music Game"),
    ("VR", "Virtual Reality"),
    ("RC", "Racing"),
]
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='./media/images/')
genre = models.CharField(
    max_length=6,
    choices=GAME_CHOICE,
    default="BMU",
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are [rendering the form fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), then it's up to you to include the errors, for example:

```
{{ form.name.errors }}
{{ form.name.label_tag }}
{% render_field form.name class="form-control" %}
```

Comment: isn't that handled with the "if form.non_form_errors" part? Or do I have to put the {{form.name.errors}} somewhere specific to display the error?

Comment: You've included `form.non_field_errors`, which are errors that don't belong to any specific field. You have raised an error in `clean_name`, so the error belongs to the `name` field and you have to include `form.name.errors` (or perhaps loop through `form.errors` if you want all errors at the top).